# From gluOrtho2D to 3D

Tags: opengl, frustum

I followed [a guide](http://nathanselikoff.com/training/tutorial-strange-attractors-in-c-and-opengl) to draw a Lorenz system in 2D.

I want now to extend my project and switch from 2D to 3D. As far as I know I have to substitute the gluOrtho2D call with either gluPerspective or glFrustum. Unfortunately whatever I try is useless. 
This is my initialization code:

```
// set the background color
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

/// set the foreground (pen) color
glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);*/

// set the foreground (pen) color
glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.02f);

// enable blending
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// enable point smoothing
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glPointSize(1.0f);

// set up the viewport
glViewport(0, 0, 400, 400);

// set up the projection matrix (the camera)
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
    //gluOrtho2D(-2.0f, 2.0f, -2.0f, 2.0f);
gluPerspective(45.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f); //Sets the frustum to perspective mode


// set up the modelview matrix (the objects)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

while to draw I do this:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// draw some points
glBegin(GL_POINTS);

// go through the equations many times, drawing a point for each iteration
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {

    // compute a new point using the strange attractor equations
    float xnew=z*sin(a*x)+cos(b*y);
    float ynew=x*sin(c*y)+cos(d*z);
    float znew=y*sin(e*z)+cos(f*x);

    // save the new point
    x = xnew;
    y = ynew;
    z = znew;

    // draw the new point
    glVertex3f(x, y, z);
}
glEnd();

// swap the buffers
glutSwapBuffers();
```

the problem is that I don't visualize anything in my window. It's all black. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: well if you just do `gluPerspective` then it's easy for your objects to end up behind your "eye" or in front of the near plane, you probably want to position your point of view too with `gluLookAt` (since your "eye" is otherwise at [0,0,0]). (*imagine the usual disclaimer about legacy OpenGL here*)

Comment: @PeterT `Perspective` and `LookAt` are available in GLM.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I meant both the build-in GL Matrix stack and the usage of immediate mode drawing. I didn't mean to say that the concept of a "LookAt" function to generate a matrix was a legacy concept.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: The difference there is that `gluPerspective` and `gluLookAt` are layered directly on top of things like `glMultMatrixf (...)`, whereas the stuff in GLM doesn't use any deprecated parts of the OpenGL API (because it's completely self-contained).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I'm aware of that. I was just pointing out that the logic of that part doesn't need to change when moving to modern OpenGL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name "gluOrtho2D" is a bit misleading. In fact `gluOrtho2D` is probably the most useless function ever. The definition of `gluOrtho2D` is

```
void gluOrtho2D(
    GLdouble left,
    GLdouble right,
    GLdouble bottom,
    GLdouble top )
{
    glOrtho(left, right, bottom, top, -1, 1);
}
```

i.e. the only thing it does it calling `glOrtho` with default values for *near* and *far*. Wow, how complicated and ingenious `</sarcasm>`.

Anyway, even if it's called `...2D`, there's nothing 2-dimensional about it. The projection volume still has a depth range of `[-1 ; 1]` which is perfectly 3-dimensional.

Most likely the points generated lie outside the projection volume, which has a Z value range of `[0.1 ; 100]` in your case, but your points are confined to the range `[-1 ; 1]` in either axis (and IIRC the Z range of the strange attractor is entirely positive). So you have to apply some translation to see something. I suggest you choose

- near = 1
- far = 10

and apply a translation of Z: -5.5 to move things into the center of the viewing volume.

Comment: Mmm.. I understand the problem. Shouldn't I be able to see anyway some of the points? Since my points are confined to the range [-1;1] and my projection volume has a Z value range of [0.1 ; 100], I should be able to see some of them. Am I wrong? Anyway, I tried to modify what you said: now my gluPerspective call is:
gluPerspective(45.0f,  1, 1, 10);
and right after the glBegin(GL_POINTS) I apply the translation with: glTranslatef(0,0,-5.5);
Unfortunately I am still not able to see anything.. :S

Comment: Edit: the transformation has to be right before the glBegin(GL_POINTS) :D I told you that I am really a newbie. The only problem now is that I see only 3 points while I am supposed to have a loop for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++), where iterations = 1.000.000... therefore 1.000.000 points. There is still something which doesn't work correctly..

Comment: @Tarta: calling glTranslate within a glBegin ... glEnd block is an error. You must call glTranslate outside of such a block and before you start drawing the points you want to transform.

Comment: @Tarta: Is suggest you determine the range of the points generated, i.e. a min_{x,y,z} and max_{x,y,z} so that you know where to look. Also to what values do you initialize x,y,z before the loop?

Comment: @datenwolf the range is not a problem. My for cycle makes the points vary in a range [-2,2] for each axis. About the glTranslate inside the glBegin..glEnd block you are right! I already noticed it, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @datenwolf I found the problem. It was with the equations of course and you were completely right! Thanks a lot. You might see me again here around soon :)